# DrillThrough in SSRS

Tags: sql-server, database, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012

I am creating DrillThrough Report in SSRS. This is my database. 
[DatabaseImage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PNoZw.png)

In my SSRS first Report i just want to display the period and status. I just to show how many Files run successfully and how many failed. This is the design.[First Report Design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yy0Y4.png)

I have written this expression to show count of success.

=COUNT(IIF(Fields!Status.Value="Success",1,NOTHING))

And For failed. I just changed the Syccess to failed. This is working fine.

This is the result of first design when i run the report.[First Report Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gddxp.png)

Now what i want. if user click on 1 which is the value of Failed column in report one. It should get me to the detail page and show all the files which where Status="Failed".

And same for success.

What i did. I change the action of Failed column value from none to "go To Report" and set the parameters. But i didn't work.
Here is the picture. [Action And Parameter Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iIAU8.png)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are using the [Status] field value to pass to the drill down report but the way you built your first report means that this will not be available.

You have 2 ways of fixing this I think.

---

The quick fix:

Simply change the `Status` parameter value from `[Status]` to a static text value that your drill down report will accept, such as `Failed`.

---

The longer but possibly better way...

Change the first report to be a Matrix,

Have a row group by `Period` and Column group by `Status`. This will save you having to setup specific expressions for each column. The other advantage is that if other `Status` value where added to the data in the future such as 'In progress', 'Cancelled' etc... then these would automatically appear in the report.

The drill down Action would then be setup exactly as you have done now (in your screen shot) and only needs to be setup once.

---

Obviously it's your decision but if it was me, I would spend the time getting this done properly